# SwiftUI NavigationStack: Unexpected Navigation Behavior from List View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm building an iOS app with SwiftUI and am encountering unexpected behaviour when navigating from a `List` view to a detail view.

I have three views: `ViewA`, `ViewB`, and `ViewC`. `ViewA` navigates to `ViewB`, which is a list of `Item` instances. Tapping on an `Item` in `ViewB` should navigate to `ViewC`, presenting the details of the selected `Item`.

The navigation to `ViewC` is misbehaving. When I tap an `Item` in `ViewB`, `ViewC` is shown briefly and then the view immediately navigates back to `ViewB`. The navigation stack has `ViewC` before `ViewB`. Stack: `[ViewA, ViewC, ViewB]`

The minimal reproducible example:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let description: String
}

struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Go to ViewB") {
                ViewB()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    let items: [Item] = [
        Item(title: "Item 1", description: "This is item 1"),
        Item(title: "Item 2", description: "This is item 2")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.id) { item in
            NavigationLink(value: item) {
                Text(item.title)
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Item.self) { item in
            ViewC(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.description)
    }
}
```

I expect to navigate directly to `ViewC` when an `Item` is selected in `ViewB` and the back button should take me back to `ViewB`. The stack should be `[ViewA (root), ViewB, ViewC]`.

What caused the misbehaviour and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the code of ViewB as follows:

```
struct ViewB: View {
    let items: [Item] = [
        Item(title: "Item 1", description: "This is item 1"),
        Item(title: "Item 2", description: "This is item 2")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            NavigationLink {
                ViewC(item: item)
            } label: {
                Text(item.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Confirmed that this works! Could you explain why this solves the issue, and if `.navigationDestination` could be used here in any way?

Comment: .navigationDestination must be inside a NavigationStack, but we can't add a NavigationStack in ViewB because ViewB is a child view of ViewA, and having double NavigationStacks is incorrect. Therefore, we need to modify the code of ViewB as shown above.

Comment: Isn't ViewB inside of the NavigationStack? Must it be exactly one level under the NavigationStack?

Comment: Exactly, .navigationDestination must be used within the same view hierarchy of the NavigationStack view.